# Dot Net Nuke: HTML Module Expand and Contract Icon

Tags: dotnetnuke

How the heck do I get rid of that expand and contract (minus.gif) out of my HTML modules? Probably really simple but I can't find the option...

I'm using version 4.09.04 default skin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a function of the module's container.

If you go to the module's settings, under "Page Settings" you will see "Module Container"

That is where you can set the container for that instance of the module.

You can also uncheck "Display Container?", but that is not a good option if you want other styling that is associated with the module's container.

If you are wanting a more global and consistent "fix", you need to either choose a skin that has a container choice that does not display the minimize option, or edit your existing skin's container files to exclude the dnn:VISIBILITY object.

Comment: I ended up editing the skin properties.  Your info got me pointed in the right direction, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Glad it helped.  What did you do, specifically?  Curious.

Comment: I ended up editing the skin's container files.  Project got back burnered so I'll have another crack at things at the beginning of the year.  Sorry for the belated post back.